# magento2 facing error during npm install

Tags: magento2, npm

[image]

-- I got this warning during npm install in my local system

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Comment: Thanks @nalinSavaliya it's working for me